# Hotend moves up on HOME command

Tags: creality-ender-3, z-axis

My Ender 3D with BlTouch And Marlin 2.0.1 firmware was working flawless for 3 months.

Yesterday, without any hardware or software change, it started acting weird: on Auto-Home command it first makes expected moves (home X and Y), then moves to the center of the bed and then instead of going down to bed, it rises all the way up and then writes a message about End Stop. This of course happens also on "start print", "level bed", etc.

Before the Auto Home command, I can operate the Z axis normally, after it, the printer does not allow movement down.

Do you have any ideas, what might have gone wrong?

Comment: Before homing the hotend cannot go down, it is default and safe to not go down. Regarding the issue please check your BLTouch cables and try replacing them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mystery is solved. The BlTouch probe was slightly blocked and reported (supposedly) being in touch with the plate. Just touching it released the probe from the stuck position and all works well now.

Due to direct sunlight, I overlooked the warning blinking red colour of the BlTouch.